# I want to convert my rdlc report in Turkish language

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, report, rdlc

```
protected void rpt_GetEntrytestDrawingTest(string searchOrPrint)
    {
        try
        {
            string FacultyID = (this.ddlDepartments.SelectedValue == "") ? "0" : this.ddlDepartments.SelectedValue;
            string BatchID = (this.ddlSessions.SelectedValue == "") ? "0" : this.ddlSessions.SelectedValue;
            string BatchProgramID = (this.cmbBatchPrograms.Value == "") ? "0" : this.cmbBatchPrograms.Value;
            string EntryTestID = (this.cmbEntryTest.Value == "") ? "0" : this.cmbEntryTest.Value;
            List<rpt_GetEntrytestDrawingTest_Result> lstForms = db.rpt_GetEntrytestDrawingTest(Convert.ToInt32(FacultyID), "", Convert.ToInt32(BatchID), Convert.ToInt32(BatchProgramID), Convert.ToInt32(EntryTestID)).ToList();

            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/Reports/rpt_GetEntrytestDrawingTest.rdlc");
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", lstForms);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            string imagePath = new Uri(Server.MapPath(MvcApplication.CampusLogo)).AbsoluteUri;
            ReportParameter parameter = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", imagePath);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;

            if (searchOrPrint == "print")
            {
                OpenReportInPDF("rpt_GetEntrytestDrawingTest.pdf");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have fixed your code format, but you have to ask a question. Please clearly explain what you want to do, and what problems you are having.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Report (RDLC) Localization/Globalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427535/report-rdlc-localization-globalization)